# Computing XML document similarity based on tags

Tags: xml, xslt, pattern-matching, string-matching, similarity

As a method for computing similarity between XML documents (usually several but in this case, two ones), tag-based similarity computation has several applications. Now, how to implement such a method using XSLT.

I think it in this way:
Extract tags and list them for both documents. Next, check for exact/partial matching between two lists.

In this regard, does XSLT provide any function/operation for comparing strings (tags). 
Any idea on the concept and implementation is welcomed.

**Simple Example:**

For these XML docs (portion of them, of course),

```
<book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
```

and this one,

```
  <books>
      <authorname>Ralls, Kim</authorname>
      <booktitle>Midnight Rain</booktitle>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <cost>5.95</cost>
      <date>2000-12-16</date>
      <abstract>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</abstract>
   </books>
```

Both docs have six elements (tags), among them genre appeared in both, title is similar to booktitle, author with authorname and publish_date with date. So, these two are similar. (1 exact matching, 3 partial matching)

Comment: What XSLT processor (and version of it) are you working with? And [yes, it's possible](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269352/asking-about-the-existence-of-a-particular-technique-without-being-too-broad/269359#269359). What about XML documents with a completely different hierarchy, and attributes? What kind of XML documents are you expecting?

Comment: Is "books" in one document not similar to "book" in the other document? Why does "book" or "books" not occur in your count? Are you doing to work with a list of words you want to find or compare? What happens if one document has an element named "author" and the other one named "authority"?

Comment: I don't think Xslt does provide any useful mechanism for the kind of fuzzy matching you are looking for. I guess you'll have to use a "real" diff'ing tool/lib.

Comment: ... and to add to cases Martin pointed out already: Why does "book" from first doc not match "booktitle" in second doc?

Comment: @MathiasMüller, If it’s so important, I use Altova XML Spy 2011 as well as http://xsltransform.net/. The provided example was a quick and simple one; therefore we probably have no control on details of documents, so they may be completely different.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, It’s a counting mistake; in fact books and book should be counted as well as book and booktitle. I know to provide a complete similarity computation of such kind, there is need to some steps of tokenization, stemming, etc. But in this case, I want to have a basic (partial/complete) matching test as simplest similarity computation check.

Comment: "*If it’s so important, I use Altova XML Spy 2011 as well as xsltransform.net.*" Yes, it is important, and that's no answer. xsltransform.net is a service that offers a choice of processors, and I presume so does the XML Spy application. The real question here is will you be using XSLT 2.0 (which allows you to use regex) or XSLT 1.0 (which does not). Note also that xsltransform.net has no provision for accessing an external document (that I can see - but perhaps you can post it through http) - so the answer here would be: "No, it's not possible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 the following takes the first XML document as its input and the second document's URL as a parameter and then outputs for each element name in the first document a list of names that are contained or contain the name in the second:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output method="text"/>  

<xsl:param name="doc2-url" as="xs:string" select="'test2015012102.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="doc2" as="document-node()" select="doc($doc2-url)"/>
<xsl:variable name="doc2-names" as="xs:string*" select="distinct-values($doc2//*/local-name())"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="for $name in distinct-values(//*/local-name())
                        return concat($name, ': ', string-join($doc2-names[contains($name, .) or contains(., $name)], ', '))"
                separator="&#10;"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So for your sample the output is

```
book: books, booktitle
author: authorname
title: booktitle
genre: genre
price:
publish_date: date
description:
```